# I have a problem with Django Admin. The screen is splitted

Tags: django, django-admin

[image]

It maybe a very silly question but my Admin site splits the screen for the detail instead of opening a new page and it becomes very hard to interact with it. In this example, I select the Sequences option and the records are shown below on the bottom half of the screen.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Solved. It was a problem with STATICFILES_DIRS. The confusing point it that either Admin panel or my app would work, but not both.

Comment: delete the cookies and try..

Comment: I did but it didn't work. Thanks anyway